# Ncurses: Difference between doupdate() and refresh() for panels

Tags: c++, c, ncurses

What is the difference between `doupdate()` and `refresh()`?

It appears that `refresh ()` can be substituted for `doupdate()`, however text does not appear unless `refresh()` is called.

Also, does `refresh()` refresh all the windows, or should `refresh()` be called for every window, that is inside a panel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From Dan Gookin's [*Programmer's Guide to NCurses*](http://books.google.com/books/about/Programmer_s_Guide_to_NCurses.html?id=Htff8VRO-UEC&redir_esc=y) (page 513):

> The refresh operation in NCurses consists of two parts:
>
> - First, NCurses takes those portions of a window that have been    changed or touched and writes those portions from the window data
>     structure to a virtual screen in memory.
> - Second, the contents of the    virtual screen touched since the last refresh are displayed on the    terminal.
>
> The copying of information from a window data structure to the virtual
>   screen is carried out by the wnoutrefresh() function. The updating of
>   the virtual screen to the terminal is handled by another function,
>   doupdate(). Together they form the two components of a refresh() or
>   wrefresh() call.
>
> The advantage of using wnoutrefresh() comes when
>   updating multiple windows. In that case, repeated calls to
>   wnoutrefresh() followed by a sin- gle doupdate() call is more
>   efficient than a series of wrefresh() calls, plus it results in less
>   flicker.

As far as panels are concerned, they are sort of wrappers to windows (so each panel has exactly one window). It should be enough to call `update_panels()` (which writes the windows to the virtual screen in the correct stacking order given by the panels) and then `doupdate()` to output virtual screen to the terminal.

If you want to further divide your panels, consider using subwindows.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer.  Cleared up a lot of things!