# How to correctly remove menu in ncurses?

Tags: c++, menu, window, ncurses

I need to know what is the correct way of removing a menu from the screen. The menu is posted inside a window I created specifically for it, see the code:

```
void makeMenu() {
  MENU *menu;
  WINDOW *win;
  ITEM **items;
  int choicesC = 4;

  items = (ITEM**) calloc(choicesC, sizeof (ITEM*));
  for (int i = 0; i < choicesC; i++) {
      items[i] = new_item(choices[i], choices[i]);
  }

  menu = new_menu(items);

  win = newwin(10, 40, 4, 4);
  keypad(win, true);

  set_menu_win(menu, win);
  set_menu_sub(menu, derwin(win, 6, 38, 3, 1));

  set_menu_mark(menu, "*  ");

  box(win, 0, 0);

  post_menu(menu);
  wrefresh(win);


  int c;
  bool continueB=true;
  while ((c = wgetch(win)) != KEY_F(1)  && continueB) {
      switch (c) {
          case KEY_DOWN:
              menu_driver(menu, REQ_DOWN_ITEM);
              break;
          case KEY_UP:
              menu_driver(menu, REQ_UP_ITEM);
              break;

          case 10:
              if (current_item(menu)->index== 3) continueB=false;
              break;
      }
      wrefresh(win);
  }

  unpost_menu(menu);
  for (int i=0; i<choicesC; i++){
      free_item(items[i]);
  }
  free_menu(menu);

  /* I can't figure out which commands to 
     call to instantly delete and redraw the menu
  wclear(win);
  wrefresh(win);
  delwin(win);
  clear();
  refresh();
  */
}
```

If I call `makemenu()` and then destroy it in this fashion, the menu disappears on next getch() call (for example), I would like it to be gone when I destroy it. Which commands should I use for that?

Thanks

Comment: It's hard to tell by that code alone what windows/panels are immediately behind. First have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14899708/ncurses-difference-between-doupdate-and-refresh-for-panels/14917120), then consider using `touchwin()` on something behind the window you're about to destroy, and finally do it easily with panels:)

Comment: Right now there is nothing behind the window, just stdscr. Weird thing is happening now - I only called `free_menu()` without any refreshes or whatnot and at first `makemenu()` call, everything works OK, menu disappears as soon as I hit enter; but when I call `makemenu()` again, it doesn't disappear .. Pretty weird behavior. 

I will try the touchwin, thanks for the tip

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I sorta figured it out and I think this is the correct solution. The problem is that `unpost_menu(*MENU)` only destroys *subwindow* of that menu, so you have to delete the frame window yourself. The cleanup procedure then looks like this:

```
(...)
unpost_menu(menu);
for (int i=0; i<choicesC; i++){
    free_item(items[i]);
}
free_menu(menu);
wborder(win, ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '); // Erase frame around the window
wrefresh(win); // Refresh it (to leave it blank)
delwin(win); // and delete
```

After this there is no need to `refresh()`, unless of course there was something behind the menu. In that case you need to take care of repainting it.